# Calling the event when it is connected to Internet

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-activity

I want to handle the event, which will check if an internet connection and if it is I will call this piece of code:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the ImageView */
    public void mapOfWasteActivity() {
        mapOfWaste = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);
        mapOfWaste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, MapOfWasteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

and if you do not have a connection to this cause me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Test.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
/** Called when the user clicks the ImageView */
public void mapOfWasteActivity() {
    mapOfWaste = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);
    mapOfWaste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(isNetworkConnected()){
              Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, MapOfWasteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

             }else{

            Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, Test.class);
             startActivity(intent);

             }

        }
    });
}


public  boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        boolean isConnected=false;
        try{
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                              activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            return isConnected;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        return isConnected;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, exactly what it was.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function. It will return true if connected or connecting.

```
public  boolean isNetworkConnected() {
            boolean isConnected=false;
            try{
                ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                                  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                return isConnected;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {       
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
            return isConnected;
        }
```